# RESPONSIVE IMAGE ON RIGHT SIDE

Tags: html, image, resize, responsive

Im trying to position my image on the right side of my screen and my text on the left, but make the image responsive as i resize my browser.

```css
#fmap{
        position: absolute;
        right: 0%;
        margin-right: 0;
        display:block;
        margin:10px;
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        border: 12px double #d3d3d3;
        max-width:850px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="maptext" id="facilitymap">
    <p><a href="https://www.google.co.uk/maps/dir//Colman+House,+University+of+East,+Norwich+NR4+7TJ/@52.6212166,1.244658,17z/data=!4m9!4m8!1m0!1m5!1m1!1s0x47d9e1e20deda5b1:0x60290452cbfc9649!2m2!1d1.2468467!2d52.6212134!3e0">
        <img src="https://4.img-dpreview.com/files/p/E~TS590x0~articles/3925134721/0266554465.jpeg" alt="" id="fmap" >
        </a>
    </p>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way using **[flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox)** on the parent `div`;

```css
.container {
/*this makes the parent container into a flex container*/
/*divs within this parent container become responsive flex items*/
display: flex;
}

.left {
padding: 20px;
}

#facilitymap {
width: 100%;
}

img {
width: 100%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
.container {
/*switch to column view when screen is 600px or smaller*/
flex-direction: column;
}
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
  <p>left side text</p>
  </div>

  <div class="maptext" id="facilitymap">
      <a href="https://www.google.co.uk/maps/dir//Colman+House,+University+of+East,+Norwich+NR4+7TJ/@52.6212166,1.244658,17z/data=!4m9!4m8!1m0!1m5!1m1!1s0x47d9e1e20deda5b1:0x60290452cbfc9649!2m2!1d1.2468467!2d52.6212134!3e0">
        <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/07/27/14/34/stars-5442598__340.jpg" alt="" id="fmap">
      </a>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you this has slightly helped, i mean i want the actual size of the picture to change as i resize my browser

Comment: See the updated snippet. These two pieces of code `#facilitymap {width: 100%;}` and `img {width: 100%;}` were added. - Setting the image to 100% means it will take 100% width of the parent `#facilitymap` div which is also set to 100%. After running the snippet click `full page` and resize your window to see it in action. - You can change 100% to whatever suits your needs.